# Cannot install Windows 10 Cumulative update KB3194496 for x64

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I cannot install Windows 10 Cumulative update KB3194496 for x64

what I have done and found so far:

cleared WU download folder, tried to install the update manually,

Error 0x800F0922 when it tries to install by automatic Windows Update
Error 0x80246010 when I tried to install the .cab file manually with DISM.

It installed fine on 2 other Win10 notebooks. more recently installed, no hyper-v etc.

I know this is currently under investigation by MS but I'm looking for a reason or workaround.

Comment: This is a reported problem, wait till next patch Tuesday, before you start freaking out.  For more information just google, "KB3194496", lots of articles that repeat the same information

Comment: I know about that as know problem, but looking for a reason or workaround. there are some fixes included in the update I need for containers/docker

Comment: The fix requires Microsoft to release a fixed patch...which happens...on a patch Tuesday

Comment: I am sure there is a workaround as the updates works on many other machines

Comment: If there is a workaround it has not been published by Microsoft or found (yet) by the community.  The reason it worked on other machines because the reason it fails, which is currently not known, was not applicable to other machines.

Comment: now the workaround is well known

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the workaround could not be simpler:

1. delete folder `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\XblGameSave`
2. delete registry key:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree\Microsoft\XblGameSave`
3. Re-run the update

[-> link to the solution](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_update/release-preview-14393222-cu-available-and-possible/7b63eb85-3320-4a4b-bc71-bb4de869b13f?page=26)

Comment: Based on my research.  I possible required [step](https://www.neowin.net/news/heres-a-workaround-to-get-the-failed-update-to-windows-10-build-14393222-installed) is to also disable the scheduled task.

Comment: not in my and many other cases.... but good to know

Comment: I can confirm this solution. No additional steps needed. Credits to TomislavRex and AirportsFan over at [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_update/release-preview-14393222-cu-available-and-possible/7b63eb85-3320-4a4b-bc71-bb4de869b13f?page=23)

Comment: It could be simpler, though. You could just wait for MS to push a fix. That's probably a better answer for most users than manually deleting system files and registry entries.

Comment: @P1h3r1e3d13 what if you cannot wait, because the latest KB includes a fix for containers which is crucial for your work? what if you simply don't care about a service that syncs save data for Xbox Live save enabled games??

Comment: @FalcoAlexander Then you're not most users.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft on 10/6/2016 released a fix to this problem in the form of [KB3197794](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53942) which once installed allows KB3194496 to be installed.

[The cause of this problem according to Microsoft is the following](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3197794):

> We became aware of an issue with the recent Windows 10 cumulative
>   update that impacted a small number of customers in the Windows
>   Insider Program that were running a previous build of the OS. We have
>   created a solution to resolve this issue, which is now live and can be
>   accessed here.

According to zdnet's Ed Bott:

> In an email statement, a Microsoft spokesperson confirmed that the
>   update, which tries to install and then rolls back repeatedly, affects
>   PCs that previously ran a build delivered through the Windows Insider
>   Program and were later switched to the public Current Branch release.

The patch is actually a PowerShell script: [Windows 10 1607 Script fix to unblock update for Windows Insiders](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53942)

The only difference between the script and performing the fix manually is the following:

- The manual method requires being an Administrator.

According to my research the script will do the following:

1. Delete the `XblGameSave` scheduled task.
2. Delete the following key from the registry:

> KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree\Microsoft\XblGameSave

### Additional Sources

- [Microsoft Fixes Borked Windows 10 Update](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/82741/microsoft-fixes-borked-windows-10-update)
- [Microsoft releases fix for Windows 10 cumulative update issues](http://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-releases-fix-for-windows-10-cumulative-update-issues/)

Comment: The [KB3197794](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3197794) link is suppose to work, it did work at some point, but does not currently work.  There isn't anything I can do about that.  The quote is taken from that page, so I must properly cite it, and its relevant information.  Depending on the length of the script, I am willing to accept a edit, that includes the script code.  Wrote this answer on a Windows 7 machine without a command prompt..

Comment: I have made a specific point, not to reference the current answer nor include the manual method, and I have specific reasons for doing so.  One of those reasons is the fact, the released update, should be used instead